# Warning: pg_query(): Query failed: ERROR: column "....." must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate

Tags: mysql, sql, postgresql

I have a query like this:

```
SELECT n.*, c.*, u.nickname 
FROM news n
JOIN ref_news_category c USING (id_category) 
JOIN ref_user u ON n.who_post = u.uid
WHERE n.type IN ('member','public') 
ORDER BY last_update DESC
```

I want the output in descending order, but after running on my browser I get this error message

```
Warning: pg_query(): Query failed: ERROR: column reference 
"last_update" is ambiguous
```

Then I change `ORDER BY last_update DESC` to be `ORDER BY n.last_update DESC` 
after which I get a different error message in my browser.

```
Warning: pg_query(): Query failed: ERROR: column "n.last_update" must appear 
in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function LINE 7: n.last_update desc
```

If I use mysql this query runs OK but in PostgreSQL it is not working...
What is wrong in my query?

Comment: You are not using any aggregate functions, so a `GROUP BY` clause should not be necessary. Are you sure about your query and the error messages? What happens when you run this query directly with `psql` instead of through your browser?

Comment: Is that exactly your query? I can't find any group by. Basically the SQL won't allow "select a,b from table group by b" because it does not make sense to it. You need "select max(a),b from table group by b" or "select a,b,avg(c) from table group by a,b"

Comment: It's a ' feature' of MySQL that it allows this. It even optimises GROUP BY in a way that it can't seem to do with DISTINCT. Other RDBMSs would call this behaviour a 'bug'

Comment: what does this return? SELECT n.*, c.*, u.nickname 
FROM news n
JOIN ref_news_category c on c.id_category = n.id_category
JOIN ref_user u ON n.who_post = u.uid
WHERE n.type IN ('member','public') 
ORDER BY n.last_update DESC

Comment: i get this return Warning: pg_query(): Query failed: ERROR: column "n.last_update" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function LINE 5: order by n.last_update desc